# Finding open covers that do not contain finite subcovers

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm being asked that for each of the following spaces $(X_i, T_i)$, find an open cover $U_i$ that does not contain a finite subcover.

$X_i$ is a set and $T_i$ is a collections of subsets.

I have come up with a few answers that seem too easy and are now causing me to doubt my interpretation of the question.

I interpreted it as: find an open conver $U_i$ that contains an infinite amount of subcovers.

Here are the spaces and my answers:

1) $X_a = \mathbb{R}$, $T_a = \left \{(-\infty,a) : a \in \mathbb{R} \cup \left \{ \pm \infty \right \} \right \}$

My answer is the open set $(-n,n)$

- it is open
- it covers the collections of sets given
- it contains infinitely many subcovers (i.e- (-1,1),(-2,2),...))

2) $ X_b = \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]  $, $T_b = \left \{ U \cap [0,1] : U \subset \mathbb{R} \right \}$

Once again, my answer is $(-n,n)$ which seems to satisfy all conditions once again. For an open cover with finite subcovers I would have just picked $(-1,2)$

3) $  X_c = \left \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : 0 < \left \| x \right \| \leq 1 \right \}, T_c  $ is the standard topology

Here, the set is a circle with radius 1, surrounding the centre point in 2 dimensions.

Assuming the standard topology is simply all open covers $U \subset \mathbb{R^2}$, my answer becomes $(n_1,-n_1),(n_2,-n_2)$ which seems to satisfy all conditions again.

Can someone correct me if I'm wrong and help lead me to a proper understanding of the question.

Thanks, Greg.

**EDITED ANSWERS**

1) $ \left \{ (- \infty , a ) : a \in \mathbb{R} \right \}  $

2) $ \left \{ 0,1 \right \} \cup \left \{ (\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n}) : n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \left \{ 1 \right \} \right \}$

3) $ \left \{ \left \{ x \in \mathbb{R^2}: 0 < ||x|| \leq (1 - \frac{1}{n}) \right \} : n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \left \{ 1 \right \}    \right \} $

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer, but too long for a comment.

> I'm being asked that for each of the following spaces $(X,T)$, find an open cover $\{U_{i}\}$ that does not contain a finite subcover.

Probably you're investigating this definition because of its relationship with *compactness*. Many students find the following adversarial game to help convey the meaning of "finding an open cover having no finite subcover".

- A referee supplies a topological space $(X, T)$.
- The first player selects a collection $\{U_{i}\} \subset T$ of open sets whose union is $X$. (The collection is said to be an *open cover* of $(X, T)$.)
- The second player attempts to select *finitely many* of the $\{U_{i}\}$ whose union is $X$. (If this can be done, the finite family forms a *finite subcover* (*from the covering $\{U_{i}\}$*).

If the second player succeeds (i.e., "wins the game"), the open cover $\{U_{i}\}$ *has a finite subcover*. Otherwise "the first player wins", and, the open cover $\{U_{i}\}$ *has no finite subcover*.

Your task is to find open covers for which the first player wins.

This "game" is mathematically interesting because it turns out there exists a large collection of topological spaces, called [*compact* spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space), for which *the second player wins against a perfect opponent*; that is, for which *every open cover of $(X, T)$ has a finite subcover*.

The game is pedagogically interesting because humans are generally better at strategizing adversarial negotiations than they are at assimilating multiply-quantified sentences.

For example, it should be clear that if "the first player blunders" (for instance, taking $X$ itself as one of the $\{U_{i}\}$), then the second player wins. This, however, is not a property of the space $(X, T)$.

It's remarkable that infinite compact spaces exist at all: No matter how devious or perverse the first player is in picking open sets whose union is $X$, the second player can discard all but finitely many and still cover $X$.

Answer (score 1):

All your answers are wrong.

- For question 1), the set $(-n,n)$ are not open for the topology $T_a$, so $\{ (-n,n) | n \in \Bbb N \}$ is not an open cover of $X_a$.
- For question 2), the set $(-n,n)$ are not subset of $X_b$, so it cannot be an open cover. Even if you take the intersection with $X_b$, your cover $\{ (-n,n) \cap X_b | n \in \Bbb N \}$ has a finite subcover : $\{ (-2,2) \cap X_b \}$
- For question 3), same problem than with question 2).

Remember, given $(X,T)$ a topological space, an open cover of $X$ is a collection of subsets $U_i \in T$ such that $\bigcup_i U_i = X$

And you want to find open covers that, if you take only a finite number of elements in this cover, they don't cover $X$.

Comment: this is random and irrelevant, but where you use your "such that" symbol in your sets, you can use \mid and it will look nicer.

Comment: Ok, I think that makes sense now. See my Edit for updated answers. I'd like to know if I grasped it properly now.